# Is it possible to find out the types that have been derived from 1 type

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, polymorphism

So i have a Type type and i need to find out, wheter there are types that derive from my type and what the types are which derive from my type and i cant just check all assemblies. Now the type i get is dynamic and i get a lot of those so i can't just check the assemblies everytime like this. I would use it, but beforehand i need to know wheter or not other classes derive from my type. Similar acticle, but he knew that he had a type that other classes derive from.

```
List<Type> list = new List<Type>();
foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetAssembly(myType).GetTypes().Where(i => 
      i.IsClass && !i.IsAbstract && i.IsSubclassOf(myType)))
           {
               list.Add(type);
           }
```

Comment: `i cant just check all assemblies` thats the way to go, what is your problem with that approach?

Answer (score 0):

So I guess, you have an object of that type.

```
Type type = object.GetType()
```

gives you the type you are looking for. And with

```
var assembies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

you have all the loaded assemblies.
Now you can retrieve all those types derived from *type* with

```
var derivedTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(asm => asm.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(type)));
```

As long as you don't load any new assemblies, this list won't change. So there should not be any need to check again and again.

Comment: You can catch any new assemblies being loaded with the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad event.  The problem is if you are creating new types on the fly with System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder, they won't show up during any AssemblyLoad event.

Comment: Thats true, but "though shall not use reflection in production code" at least not like this. It is possible, but the performance will be horrible, if you use reflection too much. And if you do something like this, I presume there is something seriously wrong with your design. Or do you know of any production case, where this is the only way? And I do not mean anonyous types like new {X = x, Y = y}, which are derived from object, and do not need to be looked for. And I assume that is not the case here.

Comment: I don't know what Danil. T's use case for this is.  It's possible this is an "XY problem", since I don't know what the end goal is, but I'm just pointing out that this answer is insufficient for the question as asked.

Comment: It depends some on when you're doing it. A lot of apps discover types at application startup, or if they do it at runtime they have mechanisms to ensure that they don't do the same reflection over and over.

Comment: @Bryce: Then thank you pointing that out. (Really, I am the last to claim of knowing it all.) You are completly right, and the answer won't cover these cases. You could do the same scan again in the AssemblyLoad-Event, but that is it. TypeBuilder-Types are put into a dynamic assebly, which can be loaded, before there are any types in it.

Comment: @Scott: Right! Just keep it to a minimum at runtime. I myself do somthing like scanning an assembly for type derived of some abstract class, to build a factory, once per start.